# subdomain redirect with wildcard

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

One of the search engines has spidered my test site: `new.mydomain.co.uk` and now I have finished testing, I want to redirect these URL's to my main site which uses the same extensions.

Example:

`new.mysite.co.uk/thispage/` needs to point to `www.mysite.co.uk/thispage` and so on. I have searched and found a solution (copied below) that I though would achieve my objective, but this cause just points the 'test site' to `www.mysite.co.uk` rather than the extensions.

This is the code I have used:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^new\.mysite\.co.uk$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mysite.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I have spent a few hours trying to work out what I have done wrong, but having exhausted my own research, I need to ask the experts to help me resolve this issue.

Many thanks

Comment: This is just rewriting the url on the browser and not redirecting.. Do you want to redirect or just rewrite the URL?

Comment: I would prefer to have a permanent redirect because I don't want to duplicate content.I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Read here for a solution https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/How+do+I+redirect+my+site+using+a+.htaccess+file%3F

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest instead of inside .htaccess, do it in your proper Apache virtual host configuration. Something like this will redirect all traffic on new.mysite to www.mysite with correct paths appended:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName new.mysite.co.uk
  Redirect permanent / http://www.mysite.co.uk/
</VirtualHost>
```

If you just include the "Redirect" line this should work for your .htaccess file as well if you do not want to edit the apache files directly. (Unless your new. and www. share the same physical folder)

A more complicated Rewrite rule could be similar to what you suggested:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^new\.mysite\.co\.uk
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

With a backslash before .uk

Ps. this question is more suitable at [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately I don't have access to edit the Apache files (shared host) everything needs to be done via .htaccess. Also, new. and www. share the same folder. I guess this means there is no real solution for this particular problem?

Comment: Not ideal, but it should be possible with RewriteRule that captures requested virtual host.

Comment: Sorry to be a little slow. Are you suggesting that I could add the following into my htaccess?

Comment: @Huggies his rule should work just fine for you needs yes. The later one at your your .htaccess

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName new.mysite.co.uk
  Redirect permanent / http://www.mysite.co.uk/
</VirtualHost>

Comment: @Huggies no, the other one.

Comment: Thanks again, I have added the redirect exactly as above and, whilst it works, it still redirects to the home page. I wonder if my host prevents these types of redirect.